# Does java support GPS time?

Tags: java, time

Does java have a standard way of handling GPS Time? What I'm looking for is a standard way of converting between GPST and UTC without needing to track leapseconds myself. It would be nice if this were tracked in a separate library that I could update to every iteration to keep up to date.

Comment: Please define what you mean by GPS time exactly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782785/how-can-a-1-year-old-java-lib-correctly-perform-an-utc-time-formatting-consid):

No, Java and the unix Epoch [ignore leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  They both assume each day has 86,400 seconds.

That same link also has a post from someone that claims to have a Java library ([Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/time4j/releases)) that supports leap seconds.  Might be worth checking out.